# how to fill the textbox with grid view data in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill the textboxes with datagrid value ie the row that is selected.
i am working on vb.net windows application

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
textBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(cellIndex).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: hello i am getting this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index "        for code:                                 txtclientcode.Text = dbgridview.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

Comment: i got that problem solved.but now again another problem arised.I am just deleting a particular record and i have written stored procedure for it, but record is not getting deleted

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter(" @CLIENTCODE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, ParameterDirection.Input, _
        False, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Proposed, txtclientcode.Text))
cmd object is not getting the value so "Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" and so i is not getting any value

Comment: @Sonali: Would you post this as another question .. it is hard to read it and answer it here in comments ..